# .mp3 Filetype Upload

Tags: php, upload, mp3, mime

I'm working on a PHP upload script which allows .mp3 file uploads amongst others. I've created an array which specifies permitted filetypes, including mp3s, and set a maximum upload limit of 500MB:

```
// define a constant for the maximum upload size
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 5120000);

// create an array of permitted MIME types
$permitted = array('application/msword', 'application/pdf', 'text/plain', 'text/rtf', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff', 'application/zip', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'video/mpeg', 'video/mp4', 'video/quicktime', 'video/x-ms-wmv', 'application/x-rar-compressed');
```

So far in testing all specified filetypes have been successfully uploaded but for some reason it comes up with an error for .mp3. As you can see above I've included audio/mpeg, audio/mpeg3, and audio/x-mpeg-3 but none of them seem to make a difference.

Can someone suggest what the problem could be and also indicate which audio type is the one needed to allow .mp3 uploads?

Thanks

**Update:** The code I'm using to run the check on the file is as follows:

```
// check that file is within the permitted size
        if ($_FILES['file-upload']['size'][$number] > 0 || $_FILES['file-upload']['size'][$number] <= MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            $sizeOK = true;
        }

        // check that file is of an permitted MIME type
        foreach ($permitted as $type) {
            if ($type == $_FILES['file-upload']['type'][$number]) {
                $typeOK = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
            switch($_FILES['file-upload']['error'][$number]) {
                case 0:
                    // check if a file of the same name has been uploaded
                    if (!file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR.$file)) {
                        // move the file to the upload folder and rename it
                        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file-upload']['tmp_name'][$number], UPLOAD_DIR.$file);
                    }
                    else {
                        // strip the extension off the upload filename
                        $filetypes = array('/\.doc$/', '/\.pdf$/', '/\.txt$/', '/\.rtf$/', '/\.gif$/', '/\.jpg$/', '/\.jpeg$/', '/\.png$/', '/\.tiff$/', '/\.mpeg$/', '/\.mpg$/', '/\.mp4$/', '/\.mov$/', '/\.wmv$/', '/\.zip$/', '/\.rar$/', '/\.mp3$/');
                        $name = preg_replace($filetypes, '', $file);
                        // get the position of the final period in the filename
                        $period = strrpos($file, '.');
                        // use substr() to get the filename extension
                        // it starts one character after the period
                        $filenameExtension = substr($file, $period+1);
                        // get the next filename    
                        $newName = getNextFilename(UPLOAD_DIR, $name, $filenameExtension); 
                        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file-upload']['tmp_name'][$number], UPLOAD_DIR.$newName);
                    }
                    if ($success) {
                        $result[] = "$file uploaded successfully";
                    }
                    else {
                        $result[] = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $result[] = "Error uploading $file. Please try again.";
                default:
                    $result[] = "System error uploading $file. Contact webmaster.";
            }
        }
        elseif ($_FILES['file-upload']['error'][$number] == 4) {
            $result[] = 'No file selected';
        }
        else {
            $result[] = "$file cannot be uploaded. Maximum size: $max. Acceptable file types: doc, pdf, txt, rtf, gif, jpg, png, tiff, mpeg, mpg, mp3, mp4, mov, wmv, zip, rar.";
        }
```

I'm getting the bottom else result telling me either the file size is wrong or the extension isn't allowed.

**Update 2:** 
I've run a print_r of the _FILES array to hopefully provide a little more info. The results are:

Array
(
    [file-upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mozart.mp3
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                )

```
        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => audio/mpg
                [1] => 
                [2] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpgBtlBy
                [1] => 
                [2] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 4
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 75050
                [1] => 0
                [2] => 0
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Without the code in question, and the error you get one can't do much to help you. Also the "MAX_FILE_SIZE" parameter is in bytes, so your limit is 5MB actually.

Comment: Can you post the code that checks the uploaded type against the $permitted array?

Answer (score 11):

MAX_FILE_SIZE is a value in Bytes

5120000 is not 500 MB. It's 5MB by my reckoning.

You'll also need to check that you're not exceeding the "post_max_size" and "upload_max_size" variables in your php.ini file

Secondly, an mp3 can be any of the following mimetypes

- audio/mpeg
- audio/x-mpeg
- audio/mp3
- audio/x-mp3
- audio/mpeg3
- audio/x-mpeg3
- audio/mpg
- audio/x-mpg
- audio/x-mpegaudio

http://filext.com/file-extension/MP3

Comment: Good point. I've now added an extra zero which should make it about 48MB:

// define a constant for the maximum upload size
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 51200000);

Also, I've changed "post_max_size" and "upload_max_size" to be 64MB. I've confirmed this with phpinfo().

The music file is 5.8MB but after changing the max size to 48MB I still get the error that it wasn't uploaded. This is just the error I set myself in the if/else conditional.

Comment: I've also now added all the mp3 filetypes you listed above so the array now reads:

$permitted = array('application/msword', 'application/pdf', 'text/plain', 'text/rtf', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff', 'application/zip', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio', 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'video/mpeg', 'video/mp4', 'video/quicktime', 'video/x-ms-wmv', 'application/x-rar-compressed');

Comment: if that hasn't worked, then you're going to need to post more info.

Edit your question to include the code where you actually do the upload (the if/else you referred to). Also get some code to dump the mime/type of the file that's being uploaded.

Comment: Can you specify what code to include and where's best to include it to print the mime/type of the file being uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should never assume the value in $_FILES[...]['type'] actually matches the type of the file.  The client can send any arbitrary string, and it's not checked at all by PHP.  See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

You'll have to do the work yourself to actually determine what type of file was uploaded, unless you have a good reason not to care about security at all (which you probably don't).  PHP provides the [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) package by default, which does the heavy lifting for you.  See [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

Comment: Thanks for the security tips. I've been building it from the ground up with security a big concern so I'll read the links and try and include checking for this. All part of the learning process but thanks for pointing it out.

First things first though, whilst I'm just working locally and I'm the only use I'm still trying to get the functionality working so any tips on how to sort out the .mp3 upload problem would also be greatly appreciated. 

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. why not use in_array rather than the foreach loop for type check?
2. when you upload a valid file, have you tried checking the values of the $sizeOK & $typeOK

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you still need this but am sure many will also be facing this same problem. This is what I did and it worked for me.

Php Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

if ($fileType != 'audio/mpeg' && $fileType != 'audio/mpeg3' && $fileType != 'audio/mp3' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mpeg' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mp3' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mpeg3' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mpg' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mpegaudio' && $fileType != 'audio/x-mpeg-3') {
        echo('<script>alert("Error! You file is not an mp3 file. Thank You.")</script>');
    } else if ($fileSize > '10485760') {
        echo('<script>alert("File should not be more than 10mb")</script>');
    } else if ($rep == 'Say something about your post...') {
    $rep == '';
    } else {
    // get the file extension first
    $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1); 

    // make the random file name
    $randName = md5(rand() * time());

    // and now we have the unique file name for the upload file
    $filePath = $uploadDir . $randName . '.' . $ext;

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Error uploading file";
    exit;
    }

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    $filePath = addslashes($filePath);

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO media SET
            path = '$filePath',
            size = '$fileSize',
            ftype = '$fileType',
            fname = '$fileName'";

if (mysql_query($sql)) {
    echo('');
    } else {
        echo('<p style="color: #ff0000;">Error adding audio: ' . mysql_error() . '</p><br />');
}
```

and your html code will be;

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
      <input type="file" class="file_input" name="userfile" />
      <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="submitStatus" class="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 5MB limit is probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will give you some symbolic meaning to your errors:

```
class UploadException extends Exception { 
    public function __construct($code) { 
        $message = $this->codeToMessage($code); 
        parent::__construct($message, $code); 
    } 

    private function codeToMessage($code) { 
        switch ($code) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
                $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
                $message = "No file was uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
                $message = "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
                $message = "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
                $message = "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                break; 

            default: 
                $message = "Unknown upload error"; 
                break; 
        } 
        return $message; 
    } 
} 

// Use 
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
    //uploading successfully done 
} else { 
    throw new UploadException($_FILES['file']['error']); 
}
```

If you're getting an error from your last else statement, it is difficult to tell what exactly triggered it. Try using something like the above.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'm not exactly sure where or how to include it - sorry I'm using this as a learning project. However, I have printed the results of the $_FILES array of the upload and updated my post above. It seems it does produce error = 4 but I too am not sure what's causing it.

Does this provide any useful info or shall I try and include your code? If so, any more specific instructions?