# Cannot upload .mpg files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I've built a rather straightforward file uploader in PHP. So far I've had no troubles uploading images and zip files. However, I can't seem to upload .mpg's. Whenever I try then it after hanging for a moment the page seems like it didn't try to upload anything at all. For example: this

```
// This is also manually set in php.ini
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "524288000");
...
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST); // I'm sending along one variable in addition to the file
```

returns nothing but empty arrays. For completeness, here's the front-end

```
<form action="uploadVideo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288000"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="extravar" value="value" />
        <p>
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
            <i>Accepted formats: .mp4, .3gp, .wmv, .mpeg and .mpg. Cannot exceed 500MB.</i>
        </p>
        <p>Description:</p>
            <textarea name="description" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

The file I am testing with is only 33MB and I tested a .wmv of similar size and it uploaded just fine.

**Edit:** Entire PHP file listed below

```
<?php
// Ensure that the user can upload up to the maximum size
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "524288000");
ini_set("post_max_size", "524288000");
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);

if(!$link = mysql_connect($SERVER_LOCATION, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS)) die("Error connecting to server.");
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);
$eventID = $_POST['event'];

// Select the event this is associated with
$query = "SELECT eventName FROM event WHERE eventID = $eventID";
if(!$res = mysql_query($query, $link)) die("Error communicating with database.");
$path = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$path = "media/$path[0]";

// If this event doesn't have a media folder, make one
if(!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}

// If this event doesn't have a GIS subfolder, make one
$path = "$path/videos";
if(!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path);
}

// Generate todays date and a random number for the new filename
$today = getdate();

$seed  = $today['seconds'] * $today['minutes'];
srand($seed);
$random = rand(0, 999);

$today = $today['mon']."-".$today['mday']."-".$today['year'];

$fileType = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
$fileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$isMP4 = ($fileType == "video/mp4" && $fileExtension == "mp4");
$isWMV = ($fileType == "video/x-ms-wmv" && $fileExtension == "wmv");
$isMPG = ($fileType == "video/mpeg" && ($fileExtension == "mpeg" || $fileExtension == "mpg"));
$is3GP = ($fileType == "video/3gp" && $fileExtension == "3gp");
$sizeIsOK = ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 524288000);

if( ($isMP4 || $isWMV || $isMPG || $is3GP) && $sizeIsOK ) {
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "<p>There was a problem with your file. Please check that you submitted a valid .zip or .mxd file.</p>";
        echo "<p>If this error continues, contact a system administrator.</p>";
        die();
    } else {
        // Ensure that the file get's a unique name
        $filename = $today . "-" . $random . "." . $fileExtension;
        while(file_exists("$path/$filename")) {
            $random = rand(0, 999);
            $filename = $today . "-" . $random . "." . $fileExtension;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$path/$filename");

        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO media (eventID,FileName,File,filetype,Description) VALUES ($eventID,'$filename','$path','video','$description')";
        if(!$res = mysql_query($query, $link))
            echo "<p>Error storing file description. Please contact a system administrator.</p>";
        else {
            echo "<h3>File: <i>".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."</i></h3>";
            if(strlen($description) > 0) {
                echo "<h3>Description: <i>".$description."</i></h3>";
            }
            echo "<p><strong>Upload Complete</strong></p>";
        }
        echo "<button onclick=\"setTimeout(history.go(-1), '1000000')\">Go Back</button>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>There was a problem with your file. Please check that you submitted a valid .zip or .mxd file.</p>";
    echo "<p>If this error continues, contact a system administrator.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is in your `$_FILES[<name>]['errors']`

Comment: do you have all of these filetypes included in your php?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790873/mp3-filetype-upload

Comment: What happens when you rename your file to e.g. a `.txt`?

Comment: @cwallenpoole Nothing. $_FILES[<name>] is undefined. @ Robot Woods I don't have any of the mp3 stuff nor the audio/mpeg (which may be useful) but as stated, $_FILES isn't being properly defined so I can't even check for the type. @ Kris Same result.

Comment: can you post the rest of your php?

Comment: @Robot Woods The rest of the file is included now.

Comment: @Mike C: Try setting the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` input to 0.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: Still returning two empty arrays :/

Comment: if you make a false .mpg and try that, does anything change? I made a file in notepad, with the .mpg extension, and I see it reflected in `$_FILES` using your html as is

Comment: @Robot Woods: Strange... I got the same result.

Comment: meaning same as I did? (you see the file?) or, same as it was? (you don't)

Comment: @Robot Woods: Sorry, the same as you. The file was posted.

Comment: So, building on Kris's comment, and that a nonsensical .mpg DOES work...perhaps there is something about that particular file that's problematic? do you have another MPG you can try?

Comment: I don't have another .mpg to try but I did just test out 2 different .mp4's and those failed to load as well.

Comment: Well through various testing I found out I got lucky with the larger file and that the upload is timing out before it finishes so I'll just have to find a way of handling that. I appreciate everyone's help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot adjust the file upload limits using `ini_set()` from within the script that the uploads go to - the script does not get executed until after the upload is completed, so the `ini_set()` overrides cannot take place. The default parameters in PHP will be in place with the lower limit, and will kill the upload if it exceeds the system `upload_max_filesize`.

You need to override at the .ini level in PHP, or via a `php_value` directive in a .htaccess file. Those will change PHP's settings as the upload starts.

Comment: "// This is also manually set in php.ini" so I adjusted the php.ini to match that before. However, I do appreciate the information. Now I won't have to use a useless line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the first thing i thougt would be a problem with the filesize but other files with this size are working as you wrote.

But just do get shure it isn't a file size problem:

When you rise the max filesize you hmust also rise the max post size: post_max_size

Comment: I had already adjust the upload_max_filesize but I just tried adjusting post_max_size and to no avail.